# Mock BuildConfig in Android

Tags: android, powermock

`PowerMock` doesn't seem to alter the `BuildConfig` field values when setting it during tests.

Currently I have these in my `BuildConfig`

```
public static final String SAMPLE_FIELD = "Sample Value";
```

I would want to change it to some other value (eg., "Another Value")

I tried `Whitebox` but it doesnt work.

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(BuildConfig.class , "SAMPLE_FIELD" , "Another Value");

Field f = Whitebox.getField(BuildConfig.class, "SAMPLE_FIELD");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(String.class , "Another Value");
```

Is this really gonna work, or this is an alternative way to change the those values?